# Convert or Choose color value for a matching string in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, colors

this maybe a stupid question, but as I'm an explorer in flutter, I wanna set a Color value for a matching string value.

well my case is an API passes a string either
"Red", "Yellow", "Green"
and I need to get this string and set a color value inside a widget of mine.
I did tried this but it did not worked.

```
changeClr(String val) {
    switch (val) {
      case 'Red':
          Colors.red;
          break;
      case 'Yellow':
          Colors.amber;
        break;
      case 'Green':
          Colors.green;
        break;
      default:
          Colors.green;
        break;
    }
  }
```

Any help guys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy paste and run the code:

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List<String> strinColorList = ["Red", "Yellow", "Green"];

  changeClr(String val) {
    Color _color;
    switch (val) {
      case 'Red':
        _color = Colors.red;
        break;
      case 'Yellow':
        _color = Colors.amber;
        break;
      case 'Green':
        _color = Colors.green;
        break;
      default:
        _color = Colors.green;
        break;
    }
    return _color;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            for (var textColor in strinColorList) ...[
              Text(textColor, style: TextStyle(color: changeClr(textColor))),
              Container(
                height: 50,
                width: 50,
                color: changeClr(textColor),
              )
            ]
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the response Reign, seems I did foolishly mis edited the method. it's good to have seen through stupid mistakes to learn.